# How to get Doxygen to recognize custom latex command

Tags: latex, doxygen

Is there a way to use extra latex packages and/or extra latex commands with Doxygen code documentation system. For example  I define the shortcut in a custom sty file.

```
\newcommand{\tf}{\Theta_f}
```

Then I use it about 300 time in the code, which is across about a dozen files.

```
/*! Stochastic approximation of the latent response*/
void dual_bc_genw(
//...
double const * const psi,     ///< \f$ \psi = B\tf \f$
    //...
){/* lots of brilliant code */}
```

But how do I get the system to recognize the extra package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name your style file in the [EXTRA_PACKAGES](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extra_packages) tag in your configuration file.

Comment: Actually that does work.  My apologies I thought it wasn't working because there was another unclosed \f$ later in the file.