# How to use doxygen to produce a pdf with custom latex stylesheet and commands?

Tags: latex, doxygen

How to use doxygen to produce a pdf with custom latex stylesheet and commands ?

I need to document this code :

```
~\doxygenLaTex> more main.cpp
#include <iostream>
//! \page MainPage Main program
//! This program is meant to say hello!
int main() {std::cout << "Hello World!"; return 0;}
```

I need to get a pdf document with my custom style `mystyle.sty` which includes custom LaTex commands, like `\mytable`, I need to use inside the doc :

```
~\doxygenLaTex> more mystyle.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/01/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}[2018/05/28]

\newcommand*{\mytable}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
  \end{tabular}
}

\endinput
```

So I look for how to use doxygen for that :

```
~\doxygenLaTex> ls
Doxyfile main.cpp mainpage.dox mystyle.sty

~\doxygenLaTex>  more .\mainpage.dox
//!
//! \mytable
//!
//! \page MainPage
//!

~\doxygenLaTex> grep LATEX_EXTRA_STYLE .\Doxyfile
# The LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET tag can be used to specify additional user-defined
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = mystyle.sty

~\doxygenLaTex> grep ALIASES .\Doxyfile
ALIASES                = "mytable=\\mytable"
```

Despite reading the doc, it didn't work: I get command as text ! Running `doxygen; cd latex; make pdf; AcroRd32.exe refman.pdf` gives :

[image]

I googled this and found [Doxygen: include custom latex command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319700/doxygen-include-custom-latex-command) or [How to get Doxygen to recognize custom latex command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058035/how-to-get-doxygen-to-recognize-custom-latex-command) which unfortunately didn't help me.

Tried a bit more stuffs, but did not work either :

```
~\doxygenLaTex> git diff
diff --git a/Doxyfile b/Doxyfile
-ALIASES                = "mytable=\\mytable"
+ALIASES                = "mytable=\mytable"

~\doxygenLaTex> git diff
diff --git a/Doxyfile b/Doxyfile
-ALIASES                = "mytable=\\mytable"
+ALIASES                = "mytable=@mytable"
```

The problem seems to be I get this kind of things :

```
~\doxygenLaTex\latex> more .\_main_page.tex
This program is meant to say hello!

\textbackslash{}mytable
```

But not

```
~\doxygenLaTex\latex> more .\_main_page.tex
This program is meant to say hello!

\mytable
```

What did I miss ?

Additional question : is there a way to **not** use `doxygen.sty` but really **only** `mystyle.sty` to avoid any kind of conflicts ?

```
~\doxygenLaTex\latex> grep usepackage refman.tex
\usepackage{doxygen}
\usepackage{mystyle}
```

Franck

Note : Windows 10, doxygen 1.9.1

**EDIT**

When googling before posting, I tested `\latexonly`. This

```
~\doxygenLaTex> git diff
diff --git a/Doxyfile b/Doxyfile
-ALIASES                = "mytable=\\mytable"
+ALIASES                = "\\latexonly mytable=\\mytable \\endlatexonly"
```

Or this

```
~\doxygenLaTex> git diff
diff --git a/Doxyfile b/Doxyfile
-ALIASES                = "mytable=\\mytable"
+ALIASES                = "\latexonly mytable=\\mytable \endlatexonly"
```

was not working. But, indeed, it turns out this

```
~\doxygenLaTex> git diff
diff --git a/mainpage.dox b/mainpage.dox
-//! \mytable
+//! \latexonly \mytable \endlatexonly
```

does work and produce almost the result I expected:

[image]

But now I have another problem : the real `\mytable` is no table and needs to be set not here :

```
~\doxygenLaTex\latex> more .\_main_page.tex
This program is meant to say hello!

 \mytable
```

But actually here

```
~\doxygenLaTex\latex> more .\refman.tex
\begin{document}
 \mytable
```

Is there a way to locate LaTex commands here ? And ideally to **not** use `doxygen.sty` but really **only** `mystyle.sty` to avoid any kind of conflicts ?

Comment: Your new question is hidden in here and is quite a different question and should be asked in a separate issue, but you should have a look at the `doxygen -w latex` and its resulting files and the setting `LATEX_HEADER`.

Comment: The problem with `ALIASES                = "\latexonly mytable=\\mytable \endlatexonly"` is that you probably meant here `ALIASES = "mytable=\latexonly mytable=\\mytable \endlatexonly" i.e. `ALIASES  = name=value`

Comment: For `ALIASES` you got it right! For the new question, I thought I should ask a new one but was hesitating! I will have a look at `doxygen -w latex`, and, if I get nothing out of it, I'll ask a new question : my `mystyle.sty` handles both header and footer so I didn't get about to use `doxygen -w latex header.tex footer.tex mystyle.sty` as I have no `header.tex footer.tex`. Still need to dig the doc and experiment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand it correct you want to use the LaTeX command `\mytable` in your LaTeX output / resulting pdf.

Most steps done are correct thought the problem is that `\mytable` is a LaTeX command and not a doxygen command, so you have to make it known in the doxygen parsed comment.

For this there are a few possibilities:

- the `\latexonly ... \endlatexonly` i.e. in the comment add:

  ```
    \latexonly
    \mytable
    \endlatexonly
  ```
- use it as a formula

  ```
  \f[ \mytable \f]
  ```

Of course you can pack the above snippets in a dedicated `ALIASES`.

So all in all I used:

Doxyfile

```
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = mystyle.sty
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
/** \page MainPage Main program
 * This program is meant to say hello!
 *
 * \latexonly
 * \mytable
 * \endlatexonly
 *
 * \f[ \mytable \f]
 */
int main() {std::cout << "Hello World!"; return 0;}
```

mystyle.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/01/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}[2018/05/28]

\newcommand*{\mytable}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
  \end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer really helps even if I still don't have a complete solution. I updated the post.